# how do I view my photos directly on laptop as I take them

Tags: photo-editing, tethering

I want to view my photos as I take them directly on my laptop. I have seen people do this but would like to know myself.

Also what programmes are out there for me to change and adjust my photos ie:- black and white photo but keep the colour of the persons eyes blue?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. (Also, please look for existing information first. On the first question, search for [tag:tethering].)

Comment: And for the second, "selective coloring".

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of methods to get the photos transferred to a computer while shooting:

- Connect a cable from the camera to the computer to shoot **tethered**. This requires both a program that has this function and a camera that support the feature. If you use a Canon DSLR the bundled program Canon EOS Utility lets you do this at no additional cost, while some other brands required you to buy an extra licence. If you have a RAW converter such as Lightroom or Capture One you can use them for this purpose too.
- Use a WiFi enabled SD card (if your camera uses SD and support the WiFi-card) that transfers the images wirelessly to a computer. If you want to get them to pop up on the screen after they have been transferred you can usually configure your photo editor to monitor the folder where the images are saved to and import and show them on the screen automatically.
- Some newer cameras has a built in WiFi transmitter that can transfer the images while shooting. How this is implemented differs but usually they are transferred to a folder on the computer and you can monitor that folder with your photo editor as with the WiFi SD card.

Regarding the selective colour adjustments almost all image editors and RAW converters have this feature.

Comment: may be of interest - http://www.dpreview.com/articles/4616822206/battle-of-the-wi-fi-cards-eye-fi-vs-transcend